# Label last row for given ID, quarter, and order of dataset, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a dataset of sales orders in which each ordernumber is divided into lots. So, there may be various rows for each `ordernumber`. Other pertinent columns are account `id` and order `quarter` (i.e., 2018Q2). For each given `id` in each given `quarter`, I want to apply a flag to **all** the lots of the **last** `order` within that given `quarter` for a given `id` using Pandas / Python. Any advice?

Snapshot of dataframe with `Last_Order` only working the last **row** of the last `order` of the `quarter` for the given `id`. Currently have:

```
 index     id       quarter ordernumber lotnumber1  Last Order
441670  10176228    2015Q2  0108595504  12947-1      0
441211  10176228    2015Q2  0108663905  12947-1      0
450008  10176228    2015Q2  0108663905  129161       0
440268  10176228    2015Q2  0108779992  12987-1      0
448187  10176228    2015Q2  0108779992  12848-1      0
439085  10176228    2015Q2  0108895691  12987-1      0
446123  10176228    2015Q2  0108895691  12965-1      1
419419  10176228    2015Q3  0109003405  12969-1      0
429893  10176228    2015Q3  0109003405  12987-1      0
426850  10176228    2015Q3  0109241988  13929        1
```

So: ordernumber `0108895691` has two lots (`12965-1` and `12987-1`); both should have a `1` in the `Last Order` column.

Any advice?

Comment: What have you done so far to get this `Last Order` column?

Comment: What does your expected "Last Order" column look like?

Comment: Last order currently is:`DF = DF.assign(**{'Last Order': 1 - DF.duplicated(['id', 'quarter', 'lotnumber1'], keep='last')})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use `duplicated` on a sorted dataframe:

```
df['Last Order'] = (df['ordernumber'].isin(df.loc[~df.duplicated(['id','quarter'], 
                                    keep='last'),'ordernumber']).astype(int))
```

Output:

```
     index        id quarter  ordernumber lotnumber1  Last Order
0  441670  10176228  2015Q2    108595504    12947-1           0
1  441211  10176228  2015Q2    108663905    12947-1           0
2  450008  10176228  2015Q2    108663905     129161           0
3  440268  10176228  2015Q2    108779992    12987-1           0
4  448187  10176228  2015Q2    108779992    12848-1           0
5  439085  10176228  2015Q2    108895691    12987-1           1
6  446123  10176228  2015Q2    108895691    12965-1           1
7  419419  10176228  2015Q3    109003405    12969-1           0
8  429893  10176228  2015Q3    109003405    12987-1           0
9  426850  10176228  2015Q3    109241988      13929           1
```

OR

```
df['Last Order'] = (~df.duplicated(['id','quarter'], keep='last')).astype(int)

df['Last Order'] = df.groupby(['id','quarter','ordernumber'], as_index=False)['Last Order'].transform('max')
```

Comment: Hi @Scott Boston, thanks for the answer, but this isn't what am looking for. Only want Last Order to populate if it's the last ordernumber in the quarter, not all ordernumber. So, only ordernumber `108895691` should have the `Last Order` flag, not `108663905` as well (both are 2015Q2). Does that make sense?

Comment: @user791411 Lotnumber1 does matter?  Just the last order in a quarter by Id?  See update.

Comment: the flag needs to hit for all lot numbers in that ordernumber. So, lot `12987-1` as well as `12965-1` for order `108895691`

Comment: awesome, might you have any thoughts on how to get this to work? Am pretty stumped given the multi-level grouping